# To center content within a <div>

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have just started to learn Bootstrap and have encountered an issue.
How can I center the content within the div?

[image: Image of the issue]

This is my code

```
 <div class="container px-4 py-5" id="hanging-icons">
    <h2 class="pb-2 border-bottom">Work Experience</h2>
    <div class="container py-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <!-- Company Information Column -->
          <div class="company-1">
            <h3>Graphic Coordinator</h3>
            <p>ABC</p>
            <img src="#" alt="company logo">
            <p>2020-2023</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <!-- Job Description Column -->
          <div class="job-description-1">
            <ul class="line-spacing">
              <li>Crafted engaging graphics for marketing campaigns, elevating brand messaging</li>
              <li>Collaborated on design concepts for seamless cross-platform integration.</li>
              <li>Produced captivating social media graphics to enhance online presence.</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using CSS to apply the display: flex and justify-content: center and inline-block properties to the <div> element, but it doesn't change anything at all.

Image of what I want:

[image: image of what I want]

Comment: Set a width in the item you want centered and give it `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block in the row has the `col-md-3` class and the second has `col-md-9`. Therefore, both columns are taking up 100% width of the row and centering styles have no effect. You'll need to reduce the width of the blocks or the row.

I changed the width of the blocks by removing the column classes and declaring `width: auto` to override Bootstrap's `row > * {width: 100%}`. Center inline by adding the `justify-content-center` class to the row.

I also went ahead and removed the unnecessary nested `div`s and the `container` class.

```
<div class="py-5 row justify-content-center">
```

```css
.row > div {
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container px-4 py-5" id="hanging-icons">
  <h2 class="pb-2 border-bottom">Work Experience</h2>
  <div class="py-5 row justify-content-center">
    <!-- Company Information Column -->
    <div class="company-1">
      <h3>Graphic Coordinator</h3>
      <p>ABC</p>
      <img src="#" alt="company logo">
      <p>2020-2023</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Job Description Column -->
    <div class="job-description-1">
      <ul class="line-spacing">
        <li>Crafted engaging graphics for marketing campaigns, elevating brand messaging</li>
        <li>Collaborated on design concepts for seamless cross-platform integration.</li>
        <li>Produced captivating social media graphics to enhance online presence.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you so so much for answering my question. I have tried what you explain and do fix the problem :) very much appreciate it!

Comment: Yep :) but I haven't earned the appropriate voting privilege, once I can do it, I will vote!

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten the `.row` and center it, for this effect. It would be wise to do that only on desktop width display.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .shorter-container {
    max-width: 80% !important;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> (view full page)
<div class="container px-4 py-5" id="hanging-icons" style="border: 1px solid red">
  <h2 class="pb-2 border-bottom">Work Experience</h2>
  <div class="container py-5 shorter-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <!-- Company Information Column -->
        <div class="company-1">
          <h3>Graphic Coordinator</h3>
          <p>ABC</p>
          <img src="#" alt="company logo">
          <p>2020-2023</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <!-- Job Description Column -->
        <div class="job-description-1">
          <ul class="line-spacing">
            <li>Crafted engaging graphics for marketing campaigns, elevating brand messaging</li>
            <li>Collaborated on design concepts for seamless cross-platform integration.</li>
            <li>Produced captivating social media graphics to enhance online presence.</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reply to the comment that mentioned `margin: 0 auto;` but the bootstrap class `mx-auto` replicates that.